# What's the correct way to include PHP from an SSI

Tags: php, ssi

I'm working on a site which uses a number of SSI's. Since these are static it makes sense to serve the pages as `.shtml` and not convert to php includes and serve as `.php`. The problem is now that in one of the includes I'd like to dynamically generate some content with php. Is the following the correct way to go about it or are there other/better solutions. What I'm doing at the moment is:

```
<!--test.shtml-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<body>
<!--#include virtual="/test.php" -->
</body>
</html>

<!--test.php-->
<?php echo 'Hello from php'; ?>
```

I've read that this shouldn't work but where I read that, it was referring to Apache 1.3. On my server at home I'm running Apache 2.[something] and it works fine, it also works on the server where the site will be hosted. So is this something that didn't work in 1.3 but does in 2 or am I just getting lucky somehow and really should be doing it a different way?

The content I'm generating is just adding a css class/id to the navigation on the site, to highlight the current page, so PHP seems a little overkill since it's pretty much going to be static after it's first generated, I can cache the PHP output on the server I suppose but perhaps there's a better way of doing this in the first place(?).

Thanks for your help.

EDIT - Not an answer, but in relation to my alternative method question.
I found a perhaps more suitable (I hesitate to say cleaner, since I'm sure that can be argued 'til the cows come home) method for my situation. Since I am not currently using PHP for anything else on the site, I'll stick with it for now. It is as outlined by [Dan M here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971334/easiest-way-to-class-current-page-nav-element/2971372#2971372).

Comment: @ajreal, Thanks but in what sense? In the sense that I can change the content on each page just by changing the SSI. Or are you suggesting I can dynamically generate content with a `.shtml`. Sorry a bit confused. Have I missed something fundamental?

Comment: [what is .shtml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.shtml). Including a php script is consider dynamic regardless whether the PHP is a static html

Comment: @ajreal. Ok cool, I see what you're saying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since these are static it makes sense
>   to serve the pages as .shtml and not
>   convert to php includes and serve as
>   .php

Well, since you're invoking the PHP engine in both cases and the entire page needs to be parsed in both cases doing it as a `.php` page **may make more sense** as you're guaranteed it will work on Apache 1.x servers as well. Then you can just output the cached page as .html as you suggested and have that extension take precedence in `DirectoryIndex`.

Comment: That's a neat idea about returning the cached page as .html. Is that what will happen regarding the page parsing? The whole thing will have to be parsed, I assumed that only the php file would be parsed and its output returned to the SSI include to be added to the page.

Comment: .shtml pages must be parsed in order to find the ssi comment strings so you're not avoiding parsing with either approach. You can use output buffering to write the results to disk. http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: Also, if the php is returned first, and then parsed in the context of the html, how does the server know that it needs to run the page through php. At home at least, my server isn't setup to parse .shtml with php. Including php directly in a .shtml doesn't work. So if it's getting parsed after the php is returned there must be some logic going on saying we've included a php file so this page should now be parsed as php. Surely if that's the case it would make more sense to parse the php first and return its output.

Comment: Sorry was writing my last comment as your one came in. I'd have thought SSI parsing was quicker (certainly less memory intensive) than PHP parsing though. Perhaps I'm just being naive though. Thankyou for the link.